# Creating dynamic references to different Worksheets

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

What I need to do is create a reference to a worksheet based on, if the worksheet is created or not (which i already have done). 
what im trying to do is the following,

```
 <Worksheet ss:Name="RELATÓRIO">
        <Table>
          <ss:Column ss:Width="300"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="RELATORIO/MODULO">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="NAME='ObtemIdentificacao_P'">
                 <xsl:variable name="cnt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position() + 1"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <Row ss:Index="$cnt">
                  <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="concat('#Identificacao!A',$cnt)">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">IDENTIFICAÇÃO</Data>
                  </Cell>
                </Row>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="NAME='ObtemSumarioSNC_P'">
                <xsl:variable name="cnt">
                  <xsl:value-of select="position() + 1"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <Row ss:Index="$cnt">
                  <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="concat('#Sumario!A',$cnt)">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">SUMÁRIO</Data>
                  </Cell>
                </Row>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
```

I'm using exactly the same `xsl:when` to check if the "MODULO exists i just use a / to go back to the beggining of the XML file and run it all again but this time to actualy do something whit the XML.

Unfortunately , this way is not working. It's probably something to do with the `concat` or the `variable`

The cycle that checks the `NAME` works  and i can already create all the worksheets and show the information i want,i just need to be able to create references to the created worksheets. I just need them to be simple click-able text , shown in different Rows.

Hope you can shed me some light and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ss:HRef="concat('#Identificacao!A',$cnt)"` I think you want `ss:HRef="#Identificacao!A{$cnt}"` and then for `ss:Index="$cnt"` simply `ss:Index="{$cnt}"`.

You can also shorten

```
          <xsl:variable name="cnt">
              <xsl:value-of select="position() + 1"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="cnt" select="position() + 1"/>
```